# How can I mock a variable using Jasmine Spy?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to test a login component. I can mock everything except string variables. How can I do this?

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-login',
   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'])

   export class LoginComponent {
   username: string;
   password: string;
   loginSpinner: boolean;

   constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) {
   }

   login() {
     this.loginSpinner = true;
     this.authService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(() => {
     this.loginSpinner = false;
     if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
     // Get the redirect URL from our auth service
     // If no redirect has been set, use the default
     const redirect = this.authService.redirectUrl ? this.authService.redirectUrl : '/';

     // Redirect the user
     this.router.navigate([redirect]);
    }
  }, () => {
  // also want to hide the spinner on an error response from server when attempting login
     this.loginSpinner = false;
  });
 }

   logout() {
     this.authService.logout();
    }
}
```

The login component has a service called authService. I am able to mock everything except the string within authService called redirect URL. How can I do this?

```
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component';
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {HttpClient, HttpHandler} from '@angular/common/http';
import {JwtHelperService, JwtModule, JwtModuleOptions} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import {TokenService} from './token.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';


describe('LoginComponent', () => {
    let component: LoginComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

    const JWT_Module_Options: JwtModuleOptions = {
        config: {
            tokenGetter: function () {
                return '';
            },
            whitelistedDomains: []
        }
    };

    const authServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthService', ['login', 'isLoggedIn']);

    authServiceSpy.login.and.callFake(function () {
        return of({});
    });

    beforeEach(async(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                JwtModule.forRoot(JWT_Module_Options)
            ],
            declarations: [LoginComponent],
            providers: [HttpClient, HttpHandler, JwtHelperService, TokenService,
                [
                    {
                        provide: AuthService,
                        useValue: authServiceSpy
                    },

                    {
                        provide: Router,
                        useClass: class {
                            navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate');
                        }
                    }]],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {


        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should log in properly without redirect URL', () => {


        authServiceSpy.isLoggedIn.and.callFake(function () {
            return true;
        });
        component.login();

        expect(component.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/']);
        expect(component.loginSpinner).toEqual(false);

    });

    it('should log in properly with redirect URL', () => {


        authServiceSpy.isLoggedIn.and.callFake(function () {
            return true;
        });


        // this doesn't work
        authServiceSpy.redirectUrl = '/foo';

        component.login();


        expect(component.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/foo']);
        expect(component.loginSpinner).toEqual(false);

    });

   }
);
```

Comment: I will write an implementation and investigate, but originally I was thinking either to use Jasmines spyOnProperty(obj, propertyName, accessTypeopt) → {Spy} or make a mock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to do this with what you already have. There isn't any need to set up another class.  First define a variable like this:

```
let authService: AuthService;
```

Then once the testbed has been set up, set this to the actual service being used by the TestBed inside the last `beforeEach()`:

```
authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
```

and finally use it in your test to set whatever you want on `.redirectUrl`:

```
// this doesn't work
authServiceSpy.redirectUrl = '/foo';
// this DOES work
authService.redirectUrl = '/foo';
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-54311830?file=app/login.component.spec.ts).

Comment: That is true...it does! I wish I could accept bother answers. :)

Comment: As the OP, it is completely up to you, you can accept whatever answer you'd like.  If you're looking for a suggestion, I would suggest that you accept whichever solution you end up actually using.  :)  Good guidance [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/165773)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
const spy = spyOnProperty(authServiceSpy, 'redirectUrl').and.returnValue(
  '/foo'
);
expect(authServiceSpy.redirectUrl).toBe('/foo');
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: The challenge is this is not a property, just a string. There is no getter or setter, just a public string.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible. Do you definitely need to test the value of the string? If so I suggest adding a setter just for the purpose of testing

Comment: yeah..I gotta admit I'm stumped...I changed authService to look like


     // store the URL so we can redirect after logging in
    _redirectUrl: string;
    set redirectUrl ( data: string) {
        this._redirectUrl = data;
    }

    get redirectUrl(): string {
        return this._redirectUrl;
    }

And added your suggestion...and still got an error of not get method available...I'm mystified....but accept your answer as correct because it seems like the reasonable approach

Comment: UPDATE: While this is a reasonable approach...the solution below fully solved my challenge.

Comment: UPDATE TO UPDATE: Errrrm....since I accepted it...the solution is now located at the top. :P

The one below seems useful as well.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try this?

Create a mock class:

```
class MockAuthService{
     public redirectUrl = "/foo";

     isLoggedIn(){
         /*This can also be defined only for spies*/
         return true;
     }
}
```

In your test:

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
    ...
    let mockAuthService = new MockAuthService();
    ...

    beforeEach(async(() => {
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [...],
          declarations: [...],
          providers: [...,
            [
              {
                   provide: AuthService,
                   useValue: mockAuthService
              },
            ]],
        schemas: [...]
    }).compileComponents();
    ....
    it('should log in properly with redirect URL', () => {
        mockAuthService.redirectUrl = '/foo';
        component.login();
        expect(component.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/foo']);
        expect(component.loginSpinner).toEqual(false);
    });
    ...
```

Comment: I think you should use `jasmine.SpyObj`, the code is simplere + you already have spy objects as methods